# Wordpress custom field custom background color in a div

Tags: wordpress, html, background-color, custom-fields

I am supposed to create a custom field where the administrator are able to change background color in a div element.
However it doesnt work.
I have deleted all css code from stylesheet that has any background color on that div.

This is how it looks right now.

```
<?php add_post_meta( 2, 'color', 'red', true ); ?>


<div class="color-box" style="background: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "color", true); ?>" >
 <p>Some sample text</p>
```

Background on that div right now is just trasparent.
How do i get it to work with custom fields

Comment: its not background:red its background-color:red. Can u check your database `*_postmeta` table and check using SQL if this post has `meta_key = color` and `meta_value = red` where `post_id = 2`?

Comment: @AliExalter I did a search for `meta_key = color` and `meta_value = red` but couldn't find any.

Comment: have you checked $post->ID, is it 2?

Comment: @BhumiShah Correct, it is id 2
This is how my url looks when i log in and hover over page link or open it to edit.
http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=2

Comment: can you pl provide me code you used to get $post->ID in <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "color", true); ?>

Comment: @BhumiShah I have only these:  
Functions.php `<?php add_post_meta( 2, 'color', 'red', true ); ?> Index.php <div class="color-box" style="background: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "color", true); ?>" > <p>Some sample text</p> </div>` From begining there were this: `<div class="color-box" **<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'color', true)): ?>** style="background: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "color", true); ?>" > <p>Some sample text</p> </div>` But i deleted it..

Comment: have you print get_post_meta on same page and check that getting value or not?

Comment: When i try `<?php print get_post_meta('color', 2); ?> ` and `<?php echo get_post_meta('color', 2); ?>` nothing happends.

Comment: @BhumiShah I found the error.  Web developer that did make this theme did have this code in the top of a div.
`<?php

$args = array(
'category_name' => 'puff',
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'orderby' => 'modified',
'order' => 'DESC'
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$my_query->the_post();

?>`
It made all mine php to not work. I did have to insert php code in to other div and then div background changed.